# AJAX response inside jqplot not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqplot

I'm trying to render data from an AJAX response as a bar chart with jqplot. To render this bar chart I use two variables:

1. s1  which contains the numbers ex: s1 = [22,67,32,89]
2. ticks which contains the name corresponding to a number inside s1 ex: ticks = ["Jack", "Mary", "Paul", "John"]

So my AJAX returns two variables, data1 and data2.

- When I console.log(data1) I get 22,67,32,89
- When I console.log(data2) I get "Jack", "Mary", "Paul", "John"

I then add the square brackets and change variable:

s1 = [data1]
ticks = [data2]

- When I console.log(s1) I get ["22,67,32,89"]
- When I console.log(ticks) I get "Jack", "Mary", "Paul", "John"

And the graph does not render, this is my code:

```
s1 = [data1];
ticks = [data2];        

plot4 = $.jqplot('chartdiv4', [s1], {
                animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                series:[{color:'#5FAB78'}],
                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticks
                    },
                    yaxis:{min:0, max:100, label:'%',labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer}
                },
                highlighter: { show: false }
            });
        });
```

Comment: looks like your data (s1) is one giant string with commas embedded. You may have to [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it first

Comment: Thank you! This worked! If you post this comment as an answer I can accept it.